# How do you make custom images editable when writing a post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've altered the default code that is generated when you upload an image through the posting page with the "add media" button in the post content.

This is the code I am using:

```php
    add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'img_wrapper', 20, 8);
    function img_wrapper($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt){

        $class = "IA_image";
        $editor_size = 300;
        $img_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);

        $width = $img_meta['width'];
        $height = $img_meta['height'];
        $url = wp_get_original_image_url($id);

        $style = "width: {$editor_size}px; height: {$editor_size}px; background-image: url({$url}); background-position: center; background-size: cover;";
        $html = "<div class=\"{$class}\" data-width=\"{$width}\" data-height=\"{$height}\" style=\"{$style}\"></div>";

        // Add caption
        if($caption){
            $style = "font-style: italic;";
            $html .= "<p class=\"caption\" style=\"{$style}\">{$caption}</p>";
        }   

        $html = "<div class=\"{$class}-outer\">{$html}</div>";

        return $html;
    }
```

Instead of inserting an `img` tag I'm now using divs and setting the background image on them accordingly. I'm displaying these images on the wordpress single page.

However, by doing this, the image can not be edited like the usual images (an edit button appears when you click on it). This is the edit button I'm referring to:

[image: the edit button]

Is there any way I can add this "edit" button to my altered images?

Comment: Its not at all clear what you are looking for. Can you explain exactly what you have done and include the relevant code, so we can understand? For example, what do you mean by the "default" image... do you mean the *featured* image? Posts don't have a default image by default. Are you talking about the displaying the images in the admin or the front end? What code have you changed that is now setting the background of a div?  This sounds like something you'd do on the front end, but then you mention an "edit" button which sounds like the admin.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I mean the image that is inserted into the post content when you upload it with the "add media" button

Comment: That's still only a tiny part of what we need... where are you displaying these images? What code are you using? What edit button are you referring to? Can you update your question with a clear and complete details of the exact issue and the code you changed that caused it to happen? We can't fix something when we don't know what it is :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Is this enough content?

Comment: OK yes, that makes it much clearer - so this is all in the Admin, not the front end. And you have added the code to functions.php I assume? The "Edit" button, as you call it, is an inline toolbar in TinyMCE that gets triggered when you click on an image, and my guess is that it is only triggered when an `img` tag is selected. Depending on what you want to achieve, there might be another way to do this. What is the purpose of changing the image in the editor - i.e. is it for the benefit of the person editing the post or it is just so that it appears as a background image in the front end?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes, it is for the benefit of the person editing the post. Do you think it is possible to do this?

Comment: If it was just for the front end, then it could definitely be done. I’m not sure though if you need the image as background in the editor, I’ll have to think about it. What is the benefit to the person editing the post of doing this? I’m just trying to understand exactly what you need in case there is another way to do it.